# PDO: Not running multiple queries

Tags: php, sql, mysql, stored-procedures, pdo

**Code**

[DB Dump](http://pastebin.com/N5njP6Pr)

[index.php](http://pastebin.com/ZEUUFJ36)

**The issue**

- Running index.php from the browser
  gives you no output when it should
  give you an array of 4 rows. ( **the issue** )
- Executing the sql statement directly into the
  database gives you 4 rows as output.( as expected )
- Also, running a simpler query such as
  `SELECT * FROM company` in index.php
  gives you the correct output.( as expected )

So there's no issue with the pdo connection and no issue with the sql statements, and I still don't get the required output.

*PHP Version: 5.3.1 | MySQL Version: 5.1.41*

Answer (score 0):

Like the answer above already mentioned, it's a security thing. They've done that to make sure that you can't insert "evil" values into the query, e.g. 'OR 1=1; SELECT * FROM users'. I am aware that you're using prepared statements, so this could never happen anyway, but PDO_MySQL still doesn't allow for this, as far as I am aware. The (newer?) PDO_MYSQLND driver however *does* seem to allow this.

As far as I can tell, that driver is currently not ready for production. Guess you'll have to do it in two queries, or if they are always called in that specific sequence, you could hide that inside a stored procedure.

Comment: My first query calls a stored procedure that creates a temporary table. I don't get a result when I split into 2 queries because I think the second query doesn't have access to the temporary table.

Comment: why are you calling a stored procedure to create a temp table then attempting to select from it ?? get the sproc to do all of the work - it creates the temp table, it populates it then it returns the data you want from it.